# Upcoming A2P 10DLC changes, $10 per month / per campaign fee

Tags: twilio

I am trying to clarify $10 per month/campaign fees.

We are creating sub accounts for every customer we sign up and assign them long code. Let's say - 100 subscribers - 100 sub account with 100 long codes.

We have only one type of campaign with all sub accounts ( throughout software)

So we pay $10 * 100 sub accounts(brands) = $1000 per month OR $10 for one campaign at main account level?

Answer (score 0):

For the ISV model, it will be: $10 * 100 sub accounts(brands) = $1000 per month

[ISV U.S. A2P 10DLC Onboarding Guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/a2p-10dlc/onboarding-isv)

Comment: Thank you. That’s what I thought.